# How to counting badge in ios using react-native-firebase when app is both closed and in background?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native-firebase

How to know that the localnotification react-native-firebase entering and showing notification badge when the app is closed? I have tried my code and there are no showing up yet both of the badges and the number. Only the status bar arose.

Here are my codes:

```js
const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
if (notificationOpen) {
  const notificationShow = notificationOpen.notification;
  notificationShow.ios.setBadge(1);
  this.handleNotification(notificationShow);
}
```

For additional info, I got from Apple Developer Documentation written that UILocalNotification deprecated in IoS 10. Should we using UserNotification in appDelegate.m and if it is yes, how to convert them?

Comment: Hi, there please follow this medium article for setting badges, although its for android but it will help you generally
https://medium.com/@samuelsuther/handling-notification-badges-with-rnfirebase-io-2acd807d22f9

Comment: Thanks for ur reference. I have tried it, but turns out that it only worked when the app running in background. Still blank when the app is closed. Is there any mistake in my code?

Here are my codes...

Comment: this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification(async notification => {
      let localNotification;

      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        const badgeCount = await firebase.notifications().getBadge();
        localNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
          .setSound('bell.mp3')
          .setNotificationId(notification.notificationId)
          .setTitle(notification.title)
          .setBody(notification.body)
          .setData(notification.data);
        localNotification.ios.setBadge(badgeCount + 1);
}

Comment: this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
      .notifications()
      .onNotificationOpened(async notificationOpen => {
        const badgeCount = await firebase.notifications().getBadge();
        const notificationShow = notificationOpen.notification;
        firebase.notifications().setBadge(badgeCount - 1);
        console.log(notificationShow.ios.badge);
        this.handleNotification(notificationShow);
      });